# How to generate and access asymmetric key using yubikey 5ci on iOS devices?

Tags: blockchain, yubico, yubikey

Our team is exploring Yubico Mobile iOS SDK: https://github.com/Yubico/yubikit-ios

But we find it impossible to achieve one of our goals here:

We need to generate an asymmetric using Yubikey 5ci and store on it. And we also need it can be referenced after generation. We don't need the private key, we just need to reference this key to generate signatures for later usage.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.